# Performing a diff on a large number of similar files

Tags: diff

I've just been handed 40 html files by a customer that are 90% identical with minor changes. Is there a way to diff all the files to see if there is a change anywhere in a particular region?

Comment: pick one and then diff the other 39 against it in a loop

Comment: I'm looking for a tool rather than a programmatic method of doing this. Surely someone has come across this issue before and my Google -Fu is just not good enough to find it.

Comment: if you are looking for a tool and not a programmatic way to do it then stackoverflow is specifically the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation, and I am going to use git to extract the diffs. It would be possible to compare the original commit with the last one, with each file being committed individually. They would all have to be named the same, and since mine are date based, I will be moving the date into the files for tracking.

Answer (score -1):

You don't want diff; you want a *clone detection* tool.

Such a tool tells what the set of files have in common, and can (arguably) be factored out.   A good version of such a tool will tell where the commonality is either exact or has some variation points, and will identify the variation points and the different values the variation points take.

Our [CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone/) tool can do this, use precise language parsers.  It will find commonality across a set of files, produce sets of "clone" examples (diff you have to run pairwise which is O(N^2) for N files).  This means that commonality is identified on language structure boundaries (as opposed to diff which show differences in term of text lines).  It also means commonality is detected even if the format/layout of the code in one file is different than another, if the meaning of the langauge structures is the same.  The site has a number of sample reports showing typical results across a variety of languages.

Comment: Linked site does not work correctly.

Comment: @DanAtkinson: linked site seems to be fine.  I see CloneDR description web page.  what do you mean "does not work"?

Comment: My browser will not connect to it, probably because it's HTTP, HTTPS isn't automatic, and your SSL/TLS certificate has expired. https://i.imgur.com/Q0TrGpc.png

Comment: @DanAtkinson: fair observation; that's recent hiccup we are fixing.    The link has been valid for the last 6 years.  I expect the SSL certificate to be re-installed this week.